# undefined breaking code processing when using sharepointplus

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, jquery-plugins, iteration, undefined

EDIT: please see John S. answer below for the real issue behind this apparent problem!

I am building a dynamic expression with sharepointplus. It should return a logical value and it does just that. I have moved it into a variable, as I use it often (reference it as a condition for if). The problem is, apparently the plus sign is stopping the processing of the rest of the code. Here's two faulty snippets (no errors in console):

```
for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++){
var category_equal_test = ((data[i].getAttribute("category")) == (data[i+1].getAttribute("category")));
```

or

```
for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++){
var j=i+1;
var category_equal_test = ((data[i].getAttribute("category")) == (data[j].getAttribute("category")));
```

No difference between them really, but for a moment I thought I would get away with this.
Here's a snippet of code that does NOT break processing (But of course this code is pointless):

```
for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++){
var category_equal_test = ((data[i].getAttribute("category")) == (data[i].getAttribute("category")));
```

In both cases of the broken code, console.log(category_equal_test) outputs the set of logical values I am looking for.

I assume it is some kind of icompetence on my part, so please enlighten me! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because at the very end of the loop, `data[i + 1]` becomes *undefined* and you can't do `getAttribute` of *undefined*, so it throws a *TypeError*.

```
var x; x.getAttribute('foo');
// TypeError: Cannot call method 'getAttribute' of undefined
```

To fix this, make your loop end an iteration earlier;

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++) {
    // ...
}
```

As for why you're not getting an error in the console, the code must be contained within a `try..catch` somewhere.

Comment: Great and very prompt answer! I did not think of this. As for the containment, it looks like sharepointplus is dealing with those.

Comment: Actually, this does not resolve the problem in this case completely. In fact, it causes a new problem - the last entry on the list is not iterated. Here's an addition to the code that made it all work:
    var count=0;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++) {
       count++
       // ...
    }

and then just use count instead of i. This is because i is increased  before the function is parsed and therefore the data does not get queried once the predefined if conditions are met.

Comment: small mistake: use count++ at the end of the code within the loop, otherwise in this case the first entry will not be processed (if it's number is 0)

Comment: I don't see how that would resolve your problem or why you need the last iteration by what you've posted in your question, but if it works then it might warrant a comment so you know what you've done when you look at it in future

Comment: I don't know how and if this worked for me today at 4 am, but a few moments ago it did not. Anyhow, right now I have got a tested and complete solution. Would not have done this without your insight, Paul!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I have ended up using. I hope this is useful to somebody!

```
function osDrawPageMenuLeft() {
var spquery = "";
$SP().list("menu","/content").get({fields:"name, link, Level, Order, category"},function(data) {
    spquery += "<ul>";
    var j=0;
        for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++){
            if( i < data.length-1){
                j=i+1;
                var category_equal_test = ((data[i].getAttribute("category")) == (data[j].getAttribute("category")));
            }
            else{
                category_equal_test=false;
            }
            var link_empty_test = (data[i].getAttribute("link") == null);
            var header = data[i].getAttribute("name");
            var header_link = "<a href='" + data[i].getAttribute("link") + "'>" + header + "</a>";
            var row = "<li><a href='"+data[i].getAttribute("link")+"'>"+data[i].getAttribute("name")+"</a></li>";
            if(data[i].getAttribute('Level') == 'Header'){
                if (((category_equal_test)&&(!link_empty_test))){
                    spquery += "<li>" + header_link + "<ul>";
                }
                else if(((!category_equal_test)&&(!link_empty_test))){
                    spquery += "<li>" + header_link + "</li>";
                }
                else if(((category_equal_test)&&(link_empty_test))){
                    spquery += "<li>" + header + "<ul>";
                }
                else if(((!category_equal_test)&&(link_empty_test))){
                    spquery += "<li>" + header + "</li>";
                }
            }
            else{
                if((!category_equal_test)){
                spquery += row + "</ul></li>";
                }
                else{
                spquery += row;
                }
            }
        };
    spquery += "</ul>";
    $('#newleftNav').append(spquery);
});
}
```